# How to overwrite values in a dataframe with NaN if it's NaN in another dataframe (Same size)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have two dataframes with the same size in python, let's say df1 and df2. **How can I overwrite values in df2 (with NaN) if they are NaN in df1.**

Is this correct:

```
df2[df1.isnull()] = np.NaN
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was your result?

Comment: Are the columns the same in both dataframes?

Comment: Yes the amount of columns are the same, it seems to work but I'm not entirely sure yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:
imagin that you have two dataframes: df1 and df2

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', np.NaN]],columns=['name','id'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 3]],columns=['name','id'])
```

In order to overwrite values in df2 (with NaN) if they are NaN in df1:

```
df2.loc[df1.id.isna(), 'id'] = np.NaN
```